# Override error message on eslint-plugin-mocha rule

Tags: node.js, eslint, eslintrc

I'm using [`eslint-plugin-mocha`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-mocha) to put some rules on writing tests with mocha and here is what my `.eslintrc.js` file looks like

```js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  parserOptions: {
    sourceType: 'module'
  },
  plugins: ['mocha'],
  extends: 'plugin:mocha/recommended',
  rules: {
    'mocha/valid-test-description': ['error', /^should/]
  },
  env: {
    'mocha': true
  }
}
```

This rule finds any test description that doesn't start with `should`.
The error message looks like that

```sh
error  Invalid "it()" description found  mocha/valid-test-description
```

I'd like the change this error message to be more descriptive but the rule doesn't offer options to change this message. Do you know how with eslint to configure this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a [PR](https://github.com/lo1tuma/eslint-plugin-mocha/pull/206) and this feature is available since version [6.1.0](https://github.com/lo1tuma/eslint-plugin-mocha/releases/tag/6.1.0) of `eslint-plugin-mocha`.

Here is how to define the error message:

```js
rules: {
  'mocha/valid-test-description': ['error', { pattern: /^should/, message: 'Should start with "should"' }]
}
// OR
rules: {
  'mocha/valid-test-description': ['error', /^should/, ['it', 'specify', 'test'], 'Should start with "should"']
}
```

The documentation is available [here](https://github.com/lo1tuma/eslint-plugin-mocha/blob/master/docs/rules/valid-test-description.md).

Now the error message is:

```
error  Should start with "should"  mocha/valid-test-description
```

*Note: the same feature is available for the [`valid-suite-description`](https://github.com/lo1tuma/eslint-plugin-mocha/blob/master/docs/rules/valid-suite-description.md) rule.*